# I am not able to install Pyaudio in my windows 10

Tags: python, pyaudio

When I Write pip install pyaudio or -m pip install PyAudio
Then it shows an error like bellow -

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SUDHAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zern0h1s\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C
:\\Users\\SUDHAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zern0h1s\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();ex
ec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SUDHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b0h1w_j0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers
 'C:\python37\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\SUDHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zern0h1s\PyAudio\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SUDHAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zern0h1s\\PyAudi
o\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SUDHAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zern0h1s\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n
'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SUDHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b0h1w_j0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-ma
naged --compile --install-headers 'C:\python37\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Did you read the error message and follow the advise given?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools

You need install MS VS [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, install `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0` - it provides required build tools. You can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159). Also, to avoid majority of such problems in future, make sure you [have Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)  - install all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Download Visual Studio installer.
After the installer is installed, launch it and go to the **Workloads** tab and select C++ build tools and install them.

[image]

After installing C++ build tools, try installing PyAudio in a **new** **Command Prompt window.**

> Remember: install PyAudio in a new command prompt window after closing the previous window.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Download the Pyaudio from this website

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Depending on your python version

**Step 2**: then open cmd on the same directory where pyaudio is downloaded

**Step 3**: Then type this command: `pip install pyaudiofilename`

for example

`pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

i hope it will work!

i also tried all of these answers but none of these works!

so i tried this solution and it worked!

Here is the ScreenShot!

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]